# Column "" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database, etl

I am trying to import the data from the flat file into the Azure SQL database table and I have a merge to merge with another source too. But when I map the fields from the flat file to the Azure SQL database I keep getting the error like

> `Column "Location" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types`

Upon looking at some forums I tried to change the data type of the field to `Unicode string[DT_WSTR]` and even I tried to have `string [DT_STR]`

[image]

The Destination Azure SQL database below is the Location field

[image]

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: In the flat file source you ticked the "Unicode" option? That would be why it doesn't match the `varchar` columns in the target table. Is the source file actually UCS-2/UTF-16 format? If it's meant to be UTF-8 format then untick the "Unicode" option and use "Code page: 65001 (UTF-8)" instead.

Comment: Try changing your Azure SQL DB Location column datatype from varchar() to nvarchar().

Answer (score 2):

Changing the columns data types from the component's advanced editor will not solve the problem. If the values imported contain some Unicode characters, you cannot convert them to non-Unicode strings, and you will receive the following exception. Before providing some solution, I highly recommend reading this article to learn more on data type conversion in SSIS:

- [SSIS Data types: Change from the Advanced Editor vs. Data Conversion Transformations](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-data-types-change-from-the-advanced-editor-vs-data-conversion-transformations/)

Getting back to your issue, there are several solutions you could try:

1. Changing the destination column data type *(if possible)*
2. Using the Data conversion transformation component, implement an error handling logic where the values throwing exceptions are redirected to a staging table or manipulated before re-importing them to the destination table. You can refer to the following article: [An overview of Error Handling in SSIS packages](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-error-handling-in-ssis-package/)
3. From the flat file connection manager, got to the "Advanced Tab", and change the column data type to `DT_STR`.